# Get a single String from an Array in XML

Tags: java, android

I'm searching for a way to get a single String from an Array located in Strings.xml without creating another Array.

This is my code:

```
getString(R.array.myStringArray[3]).toLowerCase().contains(mySearchWord) ||
```

The error is: "Array expected, found Int"

Comment: `getStringArray(R.array.myStringArray)[3]`

Comment: Many thanks, this worked: 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStringArray)[3] .toLowerCase().contains(mySearchWord)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array)[position]
```